# Why does CVS expand javascript call?

Tags: javascript, html, cvs

Why is CVS expanding the SetDropdownList call below

from

`SetDropdownList('BillPay', 'BillingState', '$State$');`

to

`SetDropdownList('BillPay', 'BillingState', '$State: Exp $');`

in the javascript below?

Should I be converting html files to binary?

I have tried the following steps to investigate this problem. I copied the html file (in which the javascript function resides) to a safe place; deleted the file; entered the CVS delete command to remove the CVS element; and then recreated the CVS element from the saved copy, using add and commit.

Despite this, SetDropdownList was still expanded as shown above.

```
function EnterPage()
{
var ElemID;

// Set the payment type and credit card radio buttons to their correct initial
// state (ACH payment, credit card choice 0).
SetRadioButton('BillPay', 'PaymentTypeID', 1);
SetRadioButton('BillPay', 'CCTypeID', 0);

// Make the credit card fields invisible.  ACH is the default.
if (document.all && !document.getElementById) ElemID = document.all['CCTable'];
else ElemID = document.getElementById('CCTable');

ElemID.style.display = 'none';

// Fill in the various fields of the form that we know about.  Note that we use
// double quotes, in case there are any apostrophes in the names.
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['ACHNameOnAccount'].value = "$FullName$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['CCNameOnCard'].value = "$FullName$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['BillingAddress1'].value = "$Address1$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['BillingAddress2'].value = "$Address2$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['BillingCity'].value = "$City$";
SetDropdownList('BillPay', 'BillingState', '$State$');
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['BillingZipcode'].value = "$Zipcode$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['Location'].value = "$Location$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['AcctType'].value = "$AcctType$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['BillYear'].value = "$BillYear$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['AcctNum'].value = "$AcctNum$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['BillAmount'].value = "$AmountPaid$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['ScholarAmount'].value = "$ScholarAmt$";
document.forms['BillPay'].elements['AmountPaid'].value = "$TotalAmt$";

// Make the scholarship donation visible, if there is one.
if (document.all && !document.getElementById)
  ElemID = document.all['ScholarDonat'];
else ElemID = document.getElementById('ScholarDonat');

if ('$ScholarAmt$' != '0.00') ElemID.style.visibility = 'visible';

// The page is set up.
return;
}
```

Comment: CVS is a source control system.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, and I thought we were allowed to ask programming tools questions here.

Comment: yes but what does it have to do with this question? you say "CVS element" but i dont see that in your javascript.

Comment: @DanielA.White I re-edited the question.

Comment: @forgivenson That's why I saved, then deleted the file from disk; copied over a good copy; added and commited it, and that line expanded. CVS does change protections, and it does expand $Log$.

Comment: @forgivenson CVS *does* change your files if it finds a CVS keyword; see my answer and the links included therein

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$State` is a CVS keyword, see http://csg.sph.umich.edu/docs/unix/cvs/cvsref-card.html and https://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/cvs/cvs_16.html

"By default, CVS performs keyword expansion unless you tell it to stop. You can permanently suppress keyword expansion for a file with the -k option when you add the file to the project", see http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/cvsbook/Controlling-Keyword-Expansion.html

The command line example it gives for suppressing keyword expansion is:

```
$ cvs add -ko chapter-9.sgml
```

I don't know what to suggest if you are using TortoiseCVS, presumably they have a comparable option to control keyword expansion

Comment: Where can you find a description of the rcs_kflags ?

Comment: I think you mean the "Keyword expansion modes" from the first link provided?  Not really a CVS expert, just remembered seeing '$State' 5-10 years ago when I still used it and/or RCS, and just started googling for "CVS $State".  Glad my answer was helpful.